# method inserting into any stl collection

Tags: c++, stl

I want to write a method which would be able to take a set or a list and insert an item into it.

So I have

```
bool getValues(const std::string& query, std::vector<T> *pVals) const {
}
```

but instead of std::vector I want to have something more generic, so that I could pass either a vector or set.  Some kind of iterator?

Comment: *"any collection"* is not a realistic use case, because you also have associate containers like `std::map` or `std::unordered_map` in the standard library. I'm also a bit worried about your original code taking a pointer. Why not a reference?

Comment: @ChristianHackl because I agree with Google style guide that reference arguments should be const and if you want to modify a method argument you pass a pointer.  I suspect I am in minority with this opinion?

Comment: I vaguely remember this guideline. It is utter nonsense, even though it comes from Google. Just look at the funny justification at https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Reference_Arguments, which says *"References can be confusing, as they have value syntax but pointer semantics.*" I do not recommend following this guideline unless you are writing code for Google. Why exactly do you agree with it?

Comment: precisely for the reason stated -- when i look at a function call, I want to know whether it will modify the argument or not?  Why do you think it is funny?

Comment: Because that's what `const` is for. And because it is *not* confusing to an experienced C++ programmer. And because the C++ standard library itself goes against the guideline, of course. The Google C++ guidelines tell you more about the situation at Google than about how to write good C++ code. Seach for "google c++ references site:stackoverflow.com" on Google and see what others are saying, please.

Comment: the difference is that const is only visible in the declaration of method and pointer is visible in the invocation as well.  I.e. int a; getValue(a); vs getValue(&a);

Comment: The problem here is the name of the function, which should be `readValue`. If a function is called `getValue`, then it should *return* a value and not take it (I know that `std::getline` violates this guideline, but the I/O streams library is widely known for bad naming :)). On the other hand, it shows why the Google pointer guideline doesn't help you much if `a` is actually a pointer variable which happens to point to some other local variable, rather than a temporary pointer value obtained by the address-of operator, does it? I.e. `getValue(a)` doesn't tell you if a pointer is involved.

Comment: well, if you call your pointer pA it might. Also my function fits on a screen so i can see the declaration of a w/o jumping around the source.

Comment: `pA` is Hungarian Notation, though, which is not used by modern C++ code (it actually defeats the purpose of many new C++11 features). And that the function fits on the screen doesn't help if `a` is itself a parameter the caller got from somewhere else. Or a member of a class. For example: `void f(T c) { readValue(c.a); }`

Comment: Hungarian notation defeats the purpose of C++11 features?

Comment: Yes. And some from C++14 and beyond. Basically, everything that uses `auto`, whose purpose is to eliminate the need to specify the type, whereas Hungarian Notation intends to encode type information into variable names, which is just about the opposite philosophy.

Comment: but how do you read code if the types are not specified explicitly and not hinted at in the variable name?  (also prefixing pointers with p is not the same as full blown HN but whatever)

Comment: I am not a follower of AAA (Almost Always Auto) myself, but I have found function calls to be an excellent use case for `auto`, because the function name hints at the semantics. `auto const filename = getFilename();`. Or `auto const find_iter = map.find(...)`, where `auto` replaces something like `std::map<std::string, std::vector<MyType<Foo>>>::const_iterator` or worse. Then there's idiomatic stuff like `std::make_unique`. Are you asking about `auto` in general?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way the `STL` works is to accept templated *iterators* for the beginning and end of the range you want to process. When elements need to be generically inserted a special *insert iterator* can be used.

```
// accept inserters instead of a container and use a template
// to make it generic (different inserter types)
template<typename InsertIter>
bool getValues(const std::string& query, InsertIter inserter) {

    // make sure what you do here works for both vectors and sets

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
        inserter = i; // generic insertion

    // ... etc
}
```

Use it like this

```
std::vector<int> v;

// vectors use a std::back_inserter (calls push_back())
getValues("", std::back_inserter(v));

std::set<int> s;

// sets use an std::inserter (calls insert())
getValues("", std::inserter(s, s.end()));
```

Comment: this should iterating through that generic iterator, but how do i insert into it?

Comment: @MK. Sorry I didn't read your question properly. I provided an example of generic insertion by passing different *insert iterators* in.

Comment: thanks, makes sense.  Moving from Java, adjusting to templates being a preprocessor text manipulation thing is so bizarre.

Comment: actually.. let's say I then need to declare a variable of type that this iterator contains in the method.. how do I do that?  I am trying       typename InsertIter::value_type val;                           but compiler complains that it is void...

Comment: oh got it: typename InsertIter::container_type::value_type val;  Seriously.

Answer (score 0):

Iterator probably won't be enough if you want to support sets. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set specifies the iterator type for set as "Constant Bidirectional Iterator" which means you won't be able to assign to it. The other candidate for a built-in type to use is Container, but I can't find any kind of Container supporting insertion that would work for both vector and set.

The basic reason for this is that vectors and sets behave differently. Vectors define an order on their elements and support duplicates. Sets don't do either.

If you're willing to ignore this behavior, you could always create your own classes to implement what you want. For instance, declare a class Insertable with a pure-virtual function insert(T & item), then create a class that derives from Insertable for each kind of container you want to use. Take a pointer to that kind of container in the class's constructor, store it as a class member, and override insert() to define the desired behavior. Then define your function to take an Insertable argument and you should be able to pass it pointers to any container-- the compiler will call the constructor for you.